# Installing Java and running JAR files on Android 4.4

Tags: root-access, 4.4-kitkat, java

I want to install and use Java 8 on Android 4.4. Using `Termux` is not an option because it requires a minimum of Android 5.0. I do have root access.

I tried to install the ARM version of Java using `rpm`, which worked but it is not usable. When I go to the `/bin` directory and run `./java -version`, it gives me an error `./java: not executable : magic 7F45`.

Is there a way to install and run Java on a rooted Android phone, without the use of Termux?

Comment: What type of Java application are you trying to execute? A command-line application or one with a GUi? The latter can not work. For a command-line app there might be a way to load the code into an app and run it in Android's Dalvik VM..

Comment: @Robert The java application is a command-line application. To be more specific, it is a Minecraft spigot server.

Comment: I don't think your phone meets the requirements of Minecraft spigot. For 1-10 players 1GB RAM is recommended. Most Android 4.4 devices had 1GB RAM and less in total. Therefore at run-time a maximum of ~500MB RAM is free.

Comment: For CLI apps you can covert the `.class` files to Android-specific `.dex` format using Android SDK (search for `d8` tool) provided that all Java APIs used in the app are part of Android runtime. Then run Android RT on the device, instead of Java RT. `/system/bin/app_process` is Android's equivalent to `java` which forks a new VM from always running Zygote VM.

Comment: @Robert I have run a 1.8 server on a debian stretch run on the same device using linux deploy and it ran fine with 2 players(The device became unresponsove cause lack of RAM).